# Android Studio pass variable

Tags: java, android-studio, android-intent

how to pass a double variable from a java class to another class in android Studio , but my second class don´t extends from a AppActivity .Can use a intent ??

Comment: show us the code of your both classes..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Intent` is a messaging object you can use to request an action from another app components. Since your other java class is not an `activity`, you should try getters/setters instead of thinking of intent